# Join two queries in to one

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my database I have the `survey_results` table which has `jsonb` `scores`: column. This column has the following format:

```
{
  'total' => 1,
  'categories' => {
    'food' => 'medium'
  }
}
```

I have two sql queries, first one:

```
SELECT ('{low,medium,high}'::varchar[])[(scores->>'total')::int] score, count(*) total 
FROM "survey_results" 
GROUP BY scores->>'total';
```

and second one:

```
SELECT scores #>> '{categories, food}' score, count(*) total 
FROM survey_results
GROUP BY scores #>> '{categories, food}';
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to connect those queries to one query which works for both scenarios?

Comment: You may use `UNION` between the two queries ?

Comment: I don't want merge results of those two queries. I want to have one query that works for every scenario. When key value is string and when key value is integer.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is start with two overloaded functions

```
create function score(int, jsonb) returns varchar 
language sql immutable as
$$ select ('{low,medium,high}'::varchar[])[$1]; $$;
```

And

```
create function score(path text, jsonb) returns varchar
language sql immutable as
$$ select $2 #>> $1 $$;
```

Then you can do something like:

```
SELECT score(..., scores), count(*) from survey_results
group by 1;
```

Where ... becomes the integer or the path you are looking for.

Basically write how you want your unified query to look first and then write functions and operators to get you there.